# Packaging requirements _and_ local modules with PEX

Tags: python, packaging

I'm trying to build a distributable .pex file for distributing my python application (Flask) with [PEX](http://pex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

If I have the following setup:

```
.
|_ requirements.txt
|_ app.py
|_ module1
|_ module2
```

How would i package this with pex?

I can install my requirements and run an app.py with this:

```
pex -r requirements.txt -- app.py
```

But how can I also include my local modules in the pex distribution?

I've tried:

```
pex -r requirements.txt -m module1 module2 -- app.py
```

and also:

```
pex module1 module2 -r requirements.txt -- app.py
```

But get the error:

> Could not satisfy all requirements for module1

If I completely leave out my local modules:

```
 pex  -r requirements.txt -- ./app.py
```

I get cannot satisfy requirements for (something in my requirements.txt field)

Am I missing something obvious here? Is this an incorrect use-case for PEX?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble. The only working pex example I could find is pex itself. From https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex/blob/master/tox.ini, I deduced that the requirements should be enumerated on the command line, in addition to your module.

This incarnation worked for me:

pex $(cat requirements.txt) . -e myapp.main:main -o dist/myapp.pex

Comment: So I still get issues with this. I get unresolved dependencies from trying to install my requirements (although this works fine in pip) - it appears PEX doesn't seem to have great dependency resolution. It feels like this is something that PEX needs to work out before it's really any use .. perhaps once needs to use it with Pants to get around this?